# React 17: Trouble with code executed twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a "presentational" Component:

```js
import { Fragment, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Card, Col, Row } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { connect } from "react-redux"
import Filter from '../common/Filter'
import { actions as tagsActions } from "../../actions/TagsActions"

export const DocumentsPresentational = props => {

    const { fetchTags } = props

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchTags()
    }, [fetchTags])

    const formatTags = () => {
        let tags = null
        if (props.tags && props.tags.length > 0) {
            tags = props.tags.map(function(item) {
                return {
                    label: item.key,
                    value: item.key
                }
            })
        }
        return tags
    }

    return (
        <Fragment>
            <Row>
                <Col><h1 className="h3 mb-4 text-gray-800">Documenti</h1></Col>
            </Row>
            <Card>
                <Card.Body>
                    <Row>
                        <Col md={4}>
                            <p>Tags</p>
                            <Filter
                                options={formatTags()}
                            />
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                </Card.Body>
            </Card>
        </Fragment>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        isLoading: state.documents.isLoading,
        items: state.documents.items,
        item: state.documents.item,
        total: state.documents.total,
        idItem: state.documents.idItem,
        feedbackSuccess: state.documents.feedbackSuccess,
        feedbackError: state.documents.feedbackError,
        showModalDetail: state.documents.showModalDetail,
        closeModalDetail: state.documents.closeModalDetail,
        tags: state.tags.items,
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        fetchTags: (orderBy, orderWay, page, perPage) => dispatch(tagsActions.fetchItems(orderBy, orderWay, page, perPage)),
    }
}
  

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps,
)(DocumentsPresentational)
```

`Filter` is a simple

```js
import Select from 'react-select'

const Filter = (props) => {

    return (
        <Select
            isMulti
            options={props.options}
        />
    )
}

export default Filter
```

My trouble is that I have twice printed in console the `tags` object, got from `formatTags` function.

Why it is executed twice?

Thank you

Comment: This is normal. Render 1: Originally `props.tags` is an empty array, this renders `Filter` with an empty array, then the `useEffect` calls `fetchTags` which, presumably updates the `props.tags` to be an array with data. Updating `props.tags` causes: Render 2: This change in props re-renders `Filter` with `formatTags`, but this time, `props.tags` has data so it returns a structured array.

Comment: If you don’t want to render Filter when tags is empty, then use [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) to return something else — like a “loading” indicator.

Answer (score 0):

In DocumentsPresentational component, you have called fetchTags twice. useEffect runs fetchTags at the initial rendering. And then, you have called fetchTags in Select component. If fetchTags is a network or cpu intensive function, then you can just call it once in the useEffect and sign it's returned data to a state variable and pass to Select component.

Comment: Where you see in `Filter` (your Select) component twice called `fetchTags`?

Last small component( Filter) is a small simple rendering component